# Determining the likelihood of all `f` "bad" samples being within `d` distance from each other in an ordered set of `n` samples

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If I have `n` *ordered* samples with `f` that are "bad", what's the likelihood that *all* of the `f` samples are within `d` distance of *both* its previous/next neighboring "bad" sample?

In case it helps, in my problem, `n=21`, `f=3`, `d=5`.

Here's an example in which all `f` bad samples are within `d` distance of each other (where `1` = "good" and `0` = "bad"). (In fact, the max distance between bad samples is between the 1st sample and the 4th sample, which is a distance of `4-1=3`, which is less than my threshold of `d=5`.)

`01101011111111111111`

and here's an example in which not all `f` bad samples are within `d` distance of each other (since the last bad sample is clearly more than `5` samples away from its left "bad samples" neighbor. (It doesn't have a right "bad sample" neighbor.)

`011101111111110111111`

(Just to reiterate: a "bad sample" must be within `d` distance of *both* its left/right "bad sample" neighbor. But of course, if it's the first or last bad sample, it only has one immediate neighbor. And, the `f` bad samples are assumed to be randomly distributed among the `n` total samples)

---

(Note: I'm not sure which branch of mathematics this would necessarily fall under, so if someone thinks I mis-guessed the tag, please suggest different tags that I ought to use.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{n}f$ possible orderings. For each of the first $f-1$ bad experiments, we subtract the orderings where that bad experiment is followed by $d$ good experiments (because this would imply the distance to the next is more than $d$). Such a sequence can be chosen by choosing a sequence of $f$ zeroes and $n-d$ ones, and then inserting the remaining $d$ ones right after that particular bad experiment. This can be done in $\binom{n-d}f$ ways. Doing this for each of the $f-1$ bad experiments, you get
$$
\binom{n}f-(f-1)\binom{n-d}f
$$
However, this is still not correct. The problem is that sequences with *two* bad experiments whose distance to the next is more than $d$ have been doubly subtracted. These must be added back in. For each pair of bad experiments among the first $f-1$, we can use a similar method to count sequences where these are both followed by $d$ ones; set aside $2d$ ones, arbitrarily arrange the remaining $f$ zeroes and $n-2d$ ones, then insert $d$ ones after each bad experiment in the pair. We are now at
$$
\binom{n}f-(f-1)\binom{n-d}f+\binom{f-1}d\binom{n-2d}f
$$
However, we are still not done, since it turns out that the experiments with three distance which are more than $d$ have not been correctly counted. To fix this, and all further overlaps, you need to use the principle of inclusion exclusion. The final result is
$$
\sum_{k= 0}^{\lfloor(n-f)/d\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{f-1}k\binom{n-kd}{f}
$$